# How to re-Order a JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to re-order a JsonArray with putting a specif Column `TransactionId` to the first element of my Json Array :

Here Is my Json

```
 `{
  "ImportOperation":{
   "Lines":{
     "GoodsReceivalLine":[
        {
           "ExtWarehouseId":"Warehouse1",
             "CustomData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Type"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"Move"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           },
           "CustomAllocationData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Grade"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"002"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "ExtWarehouseId":"Warehouse2",
            "CustomData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Type"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"Move"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           },
           "CustomAllocationData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Grade"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"002"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
    }
  }
  }`
```

Now , i tried to add in `GoodsReceivalLine` array a random UUID `TransactionId` as a first elemet of my JSON array  So that my Json would be :

```
 `{
 "ImportOperation":{
  "Lines":{
     "GoodsReceivalLine":[
        {
           "TransactionId":"RAndom UUID VAlue", 
           "ExtWarehouseId":"Warehouse1",
             "CustomData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Type"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"Move"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           },
           "CustomAllocationData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Grade"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"002"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "TransactionId":"RAndom UUID VAlue", 
           "ExtWarehouseId":"Warehouse2",
            "CustomData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Type"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"Move"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           },
           "CustomAllocationData":{
              "Item":[
                 {
                    "Key":{
                       "string":"Grade"
                    },
                    "Value":{
                       "string":"002"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     ]
    }
    }
  }
  `
```

For this i tried this code that works and generates my `TransactionId` properly but get the order of my Json as not expectedand very random order  :

```
          `JSONObject inputJo = new JSONObject((String)globalMap.get("row1.body"));
         JSONObject impOpJo = inputJo.getJSONObject("ImportOperation");
         JSONObject linesJo = impOpJo.getJSONObject("Lines");
         JSONArray goodsRecJa = linesJo.getJSONArray("GoodsReceivalLine");


         for(int i = 0; i<goodsRecJa.length(); i++){ 
         JSONObject tmpObj = goodsRecJa.getJSONObject(i);
         tmpObj.put("TransactionId",  java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()) ; 
         }
         System.out.println("*** Body  : "+inputJo.toString()); `
```

Where i'm i mistaking and how could i correct that , is my loop not correct ? please i'm stack with that

Comment: Are you saying that the order of elements in `goodsRecJa` *changes* between `linesJo.getJSONArray("GoodsReceivalLine")` and `System.out.println("*** Body  : "+inputJo.toString());`?

Comment: Yes it is , but the TransactionId is well inserted with a random UUID Value

Comment: @tgdavies , is my loop wrong ?

Comment: Please write a complete, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Do you want  me to paste json output i'm getting ?

Comment: No, I want you to write a Java program which reproduces the problem, which anyone can run.

Comment: Because i'm getting the input from a REST API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250261/discussion-between-java-bee-and-tgdavies).

Comment: You don't need to get the data from a REST API to write a program which illustrates the problem -- you can create an array with two members by hand.

Comment: I would like to see some of the output you’re getting.  It’s not clear what exactly is in a different order.